# Mysql slave skipping some updates

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.1, percona, galera

I have an existing Mysql 5.1.73 Master/Slave/Slave configuration, which is working correctly and all changes are being replicated.

I have now set up a PerconaDB (mysql+galera+XtraDB) 5.6.30 3-node cluster, which is working correctly.

One of the nodes in the Percona cluster is configured as a Replication Slave to the first cluster.  This is being done in order to provide temporary synchronisation for migration purposes; eventually, the Master/Slave cluster will be removed and we will use only the Percona cluster.

If I use the mysql client, and make changes (add tables, add records, update records) on the Master, then this replicates to all clients, and to all nodes in the Percona cluster.  So far so good.

However, if I use a certain web application to make changes, then these only replicate to the Master and original slaves, not to any of the Percona nodes.

I have verified that, if I use mysql to make the updates manually, they replicate correctly; however if done via the web application they seem to be filtered out by the PerconaDB slave node.  Note that I do not have any visibility of the exact SQL being used by the application, and cannot stop the database in order to enable query logging.

Using `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` and `SHOW MASTER STATUS` I can see that the log position is increasing on both master and slave when a change is made.

Can anyone tell me any reason why an update from the webapp would be ignored by the Percona slave thread, when a 'manual' SQL command to do the same update appears to replicate correctly?  Is this a version incompatibility, and is there any temporary workaround?

Master configuration (part)

`[mysqld]
binlog-format = mixed
binlog-ignore-db = mysql
binlog-ignore-db = information_schema
expire_logs_days = 10
log-bin = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
server-id = 1
skip-external-locking
sync_binlog = 1`

Slave configuration (part)

`[mysqld]
server-id = 1000
log-slave-updates = 1
relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
log_bin = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
slave-skip-error = 1062,1050
replicate-ignore-db = mysql
replicate-ignore-db = information_schema
replicate-ignore-db = performance_schema`

Master status:

            `File: mysql-bin.000027
        Position: 1563
    Binlog_Do_DB: 
Binlog_Ignore_DB: mysql,information_schema`

Slave status:

               `Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: x.x.x.x
                  Master_User: replication
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000027
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1563
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000012
                Relay_Log_Pos: 269
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000027
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: mysql,information_schema,performance_schema
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1563
              Relay_Log_Space: 442
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0`

Warnings appearing on the Slave side:

`2016-09-07 20:16:26 21354 [Warning] Slave I/O: Notifying master by SET @master_binlog_checksum= @@global.binlog_checksum failed with error: Unknown system variable 'binlog_checksum', Error_code: 1193
2016-09-07 20:16:26 21354 [Warning] Slave I/O: Unknown system variable 'SERVER_UUID' on master. A probable cause is that the variable is not supported on the master (version: 5.1.73-log), even though it is on the slave (version: 5.6.30-76.3-56-log), Error_code: 1193`

Comment: I have heard of issues caused by using 'binlog_do_db' when a client does not use 'use dbname'; however this affects ALL slaves, whereas in my case we don't use the binlog_do_db and only the 5.6 slave is affected.

Comment: it could be the `replicate-ignore-db` options causing the problem you mentioned with the `USE dbname` query. Or the `Slave-Skip-Error` - could those queries be causing an error?

Comment: @IGGt - I thought of that, but the database I'm working with is not one of the ignored ones -- and in any case, it replicates fine if I manually run the SQL myself, only fails when the changes are done by the app.  The errors being skipped are duplicate key errors (record already exists) and 'table already exists' so do not apply to updates

Comment: replication from 5.1 to 5.6 is not really supported, you may need to add an intermediate slave (5.5) in between 5.1 and 5.6, or upgrade 5.1 to 5.5 or 5.6

Comment: @jerichorivera - I know its a bit of a jump.  This is only a temporary thing to try and upgrade to Percona (5.6) from the old 5.1 setup without an outage (there is an HAProxy over the top of everything).  I was hoping that there was a kludge to make it work for the short migration period, without needing a separate host :(

Comment: Check the server_id values.  Since 5.1 is in use, check that GTID is not in use.  Semi-related: [_Tips on converting to Galera_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/tips-on-converting-to-galera/)

Comment: The server_ids are definitely different.  The application is certified to work with Perconadb, so should be behaving...  What confuses me is that it is only the replication to the Galera cluster that fails, not to the 5.1 slaves, and only when the change originated with the app, not when I do a SQL UPDATE manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  At some point in the past, someone had reconfigured the 5.1 cluster so that node 2 became the master and node 1 the slave.  This meant that I was actually replicating from a slave to the Galera cluster, and the application was writing to node 2.

This should still work; however the old master (node 1) did not have the `log-slave-updates` setting, and so updates form the application coming in via the (master) node 2 were not replicated on to the Galera cluster.

I changed to replicate from node 2 (the real master) and everything worked as expected.

So, in summary, it was a Layer 8 problem (IE, user error) caused by replicating from a slave without log-slave-updates set.